# Extended Euclid algorithm - is there non-recursive version of it?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I implemented the following version of the extended Euclidian algorithm:

```c
long gcdex(const long& a, const long& b, long& x, long& y)
{
    if (a == 0) {
        x = 0; y = 1;
        return b;
    }
    
    long x1, y1;
    long d = gcdex(b % a, a, x1, y1);
    x = y1 - (b / a) * x1;
    y = x1;
    return d;
}
```

I don't know how to implement the non-recursive version of it, can you help me with that?

Comment: This code is meant to find x and y in [Bezout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) right?

Comment: There's pseudo code of an iterative version right there in the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Pseudocode), it just turns into a loop and simple variables, you don't have to simulate a stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any recursive algorithm can be implemented as non-recursive using iteration and an additional stack. Still this will cause some algorithms to become far less readable and also it may not improve the efficiency.

I like your version of the algorithm - it is short and readable(perhaps you need to rename some variables though) and it gives you the best possible complexity of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to implement the extended euklidian algorithm without stack and recursion:

```py
# Just a wrapper class to represent extended euklidian algorithm result
class GCD_Result:
    def __init__(self, gcd, u, v):
        self.gcd = gcd
        # u and v are the linear combination coefficients
        self.u = u
        self.v = v
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.gcd) + " = " + str(self.u) + " * a + " + str(self.v) + " * b"

def extended_gcd(a, b):
    if a == 0:
        return GCD_Result(b, 0, 1)

    unPrev = 1
    vnPrev = 0
    unCur = 0
    vnCur = 1

    while b != 0:
        bn = a // b
        newB = a % b
        a = b
        b = newB

        # Update coefficients
        unNew = unPrev - bn * unCur
        vnNew = vnPrev - bn * vnCur

        # Shift coefficients
        unPrev = unCur
        vnPrev = vnCur
        unCur = unNew
        vnCur = vnNew

    return GCD_Result(a, unPrev, vnPrev)
```

It is hard to implement this algorithm without stack because we normally do the backwards substitution when we are cligming out of the recursive calls. An by doing so we make our algorithm non-tail-recursive. What my algortithm does is it updates the coefficients step-by-step as a and b update.

Answer (score 0):

As Ivaylo Strandjev said, any recursive algorithm can be implemented as non-recursive using iteration and an additional stack.
But for some questions, we can use some special skills to implement. For this question, we can calculate x and y with the help of linear algebra.

```
// non-recursive
void gcd_exd_non_rec(int a, int b, int &x, int &y) {
     std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(2);
     vec[0] = {1, 0, a};
     vec[1] = {0, 1, b};
     while (vec[1][2]) {
         int q = vec[0][2] / vec[1][2];
         std::vector<int> tmp_0 = vec[1];
         // just a vector arithmetic: vec[0] - q * vec[1]
         std::vector<int> tmp_1 = {vec[0][0] - q * vec[1][0], vec[0][1] - q * vec[1][1], vec[0][2] - q * vec[1][2]};
         vec[0] = tmp_0;
         vec[1] = tmp_1;
     }
     x = vec[0][0];
     y = vec[0][1];
     return;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions are absolutely correct but I think seeing the transformation helps with understanding why this works, and that this is a fairly general approach.

Here is the recursive implementation:

```py
def extended_gcd(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return a, 1, 0
    (d,m) = divmod(a,b)
    (r,x,y) = extended_gcd(b,m)
    return (r, y, x - d * y)
```

The last 'continuation' is a linear transformation of the result - the first entry could be `1 * r + 0 * x + 0 * y`. We can store these coefficients in a matrix, store all the matrices until the end, and apply them using matrix multiplication:

```py
import numpy as np
def extended_gcd(a, b):
    out = []
    while b != 0:
        (d,m) = divmod(a,b)
        a,b= b,m
        out.append(np.array([[1,0,0], [0,0,1], [0, 1, -d]]))
    result = [a, 1, 0]
    for o in reversed(out):
        result = o @ result
    return result
```

But matrix multiplication can also be used as function composition, which is associative. So we can do the multiplication along the way:

```py
def extended_gcd(a, b):
    out = np.identity(3)
    while b != 0:
        (d,m) = divmod(a,b)
        a,b= b,m
        out = out @ [[1,0,0], [0,0,1], [0, 1, -d]]
    return out @ [a, 1, 0]
```

The first row is always `[1,0,0]`, so removing that row and simplifying leaves us with

```py
def extended_gcd(a, b):
    out = np.identity(2)
    while b != 0:
        (d,m) = divmod(a,b)
        a,b= b,m
        out = out @ [[0,1], [1, -d]]
    return (a, out[0,0], out[1,0])
```

This is what the other answers do, modulo inlining the matrix multiplication. This is a useful trick to know because it lets you turn any recursive 'tail-linear' function into a loop.